# Error at Delphi : Dataset not in edit or insert mode

Tags: delphi

Right now I'm struggling to solve a bug that caused by the dataset mode at Delphi (using ADODataset),

details as below for the add button mechanism :

```
IDMain: =self.DBTextIDUser.Caption+'-'+self.DBEditWorkingDate.Text;
datamodule1.ADODataSetWorkingDetails.Append;

with datamodule1.ADODataSetWorkingDetails do

begin

  dbgridworkinghours.Fields[0].AsString := IDMain;
  dbgridworkinghours.Fields[7].AsString := self.DBTextIDUser.Caption;
  dbgridworkinghours.Fields[8].AsString := self.DBTextName.Caption;
  dbgridworkinghours.Fields[9].AsString := self.DBEditWorkingDate.Text;
  dbgridworkinghours.Fields[11].AsString := self.DBTextPeriod.caption;
  dbgridworkinghours.Fields[10].AsString := self.DBTextToday.Caption;

end;
```

I already set the adodataset to append mode at the save button :

```
datamodule1.ADODataSetWorkingDetails.post;
```

when I click the save button, an error appears that:

> The adodataset not in edit/insert mode

I already used this mechanism at the other form and it works

note: I already tried setting the adodataset mode to insert, but still faced the same error

Comment: Is the grid connected to the dataset? More important  Why do you asaign the values to the grid instead of the dataset?

Comment: check other events of the adodataset.

Comment: Hi, the Post is at the save button : datamodule1.ADODataSetWorkingDetails.post. What I meant in before, the append mode already set at the add button. for the Post, I already put it at the save button (datamodule1.ADODataSetWorkingDetails.post)

Answer (score 3):

What @kobik said.

Your problem is most likely being caused by something you haven't told us in your q.
I think the important thing is for you to find out how to debug this sort of thing
yourself, so that even if you don't understand the cause, you can at least isolate
it and provide better information when you ask for help here.  So I'm going to
outline how to do that.

- In your Project Options, check the box "Use Debug DCUs"
- Set up two event handlers, for your ADODataSetWorkingDetails's
  `AfterPost` and `AfterScroll` events, put a some "do nothing" code in both of them
  (to stop the IDE removing them). Put a debugger breakpoint on the first line
  inside the `AfterScroll` handler, but not (yet) the `AfterScroll` one.
- Compile and run your program.
- You should find that somewhere after you call `Append` but before you click your
  Save button, the debugger stops on your `AfterPost` breakpoint.
- When it does,
  go to `View | Debug windows | Call stack`.  This will show you a list of
  program lines, the one at the top being the one closest to where the breakpoint
  tripped.  This will likely be deep inside the VCL's run-time code (which is why
  I said to check "Use Debug DCUs".  Scroll down the list towards the bottom, and
  eventually you should come to a  line which is the cause of *why* `Post` was called.
- If it isn't obvious to you why the `AfterPost` event was called, put a breakpoint
  on your `Append` line and run the program again.  When this breakpoint trips,
  put another breakpoint inside your `AfterScroll` event, resume the program
  by pressing F9 and see if the `AfterScroll` breakpoint is hit.  If
  it is, again view the `Call stack` and that should show you why it was called -
  if it isn't obvious, then add the contents of tthe `Call stack` window to your q.
  If the cause **is** obvious, then change your code to avoid it.

The reason I've gone on about the `AfterScroll` event is that what isn't obvious
is that when your code causes a dataset to scroll, any pending change (because
the dtaset is in dsInsert or dsEdit state will cause the change to be posted
and you will then got the error you've quoted if you try to call `Post` on the
dataset again.  Calling `Append` initially sets a dataset into dsInsert state, btw.

See if you can at least identify what is causing your dataset to post before
it is supposed to, and let us know in a comment to your q or this answer.

Btw, I strongly recommend that you get out of the habit of using the `with` construct in your code.  Although it may save you a bit of typing, in the long term it will likely make bugs far more likely to happen and far harder to find.

**Update** `TDataSet` and its descendants have a `State` property which is of type `TDataSetState` (see
DB.Pas).  Normally, for browsing data and navigating around the dataset, the
dataset is in `dsBrowse` state.  If you call `Edit` or `Append` (or `Insert`), the dataset
is temporarily put in dsEdit or dsInsert state, respectively.  Various routines in DB.Pas
check the dataset state before certain operations are performed and raise an exception if the
`DataSet` in not in the correct state for the operation to go ahead.  It is very, very likely
that it is one of these checks that is giving you the exception.

My original hunch was that your error was occurring because something was happening which
was causing `Post` to be called, because if `Post` succeeds, it puts the dataset back into
`dsBrowse` state, so when clicking your Save button calls `Post`, the dataset is already
in `dsBrowse` state.  You can, of course, put a breakpoint in TDataSet.Post in DB.Pas
check which state the dataset is actually in when it is called.

There are two other main possibilities for the cause of your exception, namely that
either TDataSet.Cancel or the general Abort method is being called.  To investigate
these, put breakpoints on the first lines inside `TDataSet.Cancel` (in DB.Pas) and
`Abort` (in SysUtils.Pas).  If either of these breakpoints trips between you calling
`Append` and `Post`, then you can use the Call Stack view to try and figure
out why execution has reached there.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your conclusions about an event being assigned to the dataset. I can't see a `Post` in the user code, except what he mentioned: `I already set the adodataset to append mode at the save button: datamodule1.ADODataSetWorkingDetails.post;`. What does that mean? I have no clue. it's not clear where it happens. a scroll will happen after the Append so I'm also not sure about the `AfterScroll` event you mentioned (or maybe I misunderstand you answer completely). I voted to close the question.

Comment: @kobik:  I wasn't intending to suggest that it is an event that the OP has set up which is causing the problem and I have no idea what the OP means by "I already set ... **at** the save button.  I'm guessing that the new record is getting automatically posted without the OP realising it - he mention "the other form" - maybe something is going on with that.  Anyway, pursuing our regular contributor  David H's theme that questioners should learn to debug their own problems, I was just hoping to point the OP in the direction of being able to do that.

Comment: Hi, the append mode, I already set it at the add button that I already created. For the post, set it on the save button that I already created

Comment: @TimmyBudiman:  Ok, but you didn't say whether you have had any success trying what I've explained in my answer.  I've added an Update section which explains two other possible causes you can investigate using debugger breakpoints.

Comment: @MartynA sory for the late reply, I already tried based on your explaination and the problem solved. Thank you very much

Comment: @TimmyBudiman:  Glad it worked.  Please consider "accepting" my answer by clicking the "tick" icon next to its top lefthand side.